# Sass @imports hierarchy: Bottom to top or top to bottom?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am working on a project where I am using scss for the first time. We have a main file which `@imports` all the other files; which might also import some other files.

It is taking ages to compile. People have said this is the normal approach when using Sass. But I suspect that it could be more interesting to follow the opposite approach - to have many files that would `@import` only the common parts.

What is the best way to go on this? How can I optimize the Sass imports?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Having a `main.scss` that imports other partials (scss files with an underscore) is the right way to go.  This is fairly opinionated but I only use `@import` in the main file and not in partials.  For me this can lead to importing things that you may not realise and also that you may not need, bloating your CSS.  Keep it simple.

Secondly, you could try using [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) to compile your SASS. Libsass is a port of the original ruby project and compilies a lot faster.  It is not fully featured, but is worth giving a go, and may speed up your compiles without having to touch the SASS files.

Here a good blog post on the subject - [lightning fast sass compiling with libsass node sass and grunt-sass/](http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/)